# How do I display an image as the Blazor WebAssembly Pre-Render Loads?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Currently, If I were to run Blazor WebAssembly with render-mode as WebAssembly, then I can show a Spinner that increases to 100% and my logo. However, if I set the WebAssembly app to load as Pre-Render, then the spinner icon stays on the page above my content. In the scenarios, where the site pre-renders, this loads fast, but when it doesn't meet the pre-render criteria and has to load with render-mode as webassembly then it's just a blank white screen for a few seconds.

I tried adding the div in the start of the else statement, but that image and spinner stay on the page when the app finishes loading.

```
    <div id="app">
        @if (HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Welcome") || HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/About-Us"))
        {
            <component type="typeof(Web.Client.App)"
                       render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />
        }
        else
        {
**            <div style="position:fixed;top:5px;left:5px;">
                <img src="/images/Logo.png" style="height:60px;" alt="Logo" />
                <svg class="loading-progress">
                    <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
                    <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
                </svg>
                <div class="loading-progress-text"></div>
            </div>**
            <component type="typeof(Web.Client.App)"
                       render-mode="**WebAssembly**" />
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: pls allow me to post my ideas as a reply below to explain my ideas better. To summarize it, when we use `WebAssemblyPrerendered`, we don't need to have `<div id="app">` part along with the Spinner. If we still add this code into the _Host.cshtml, they would be loaded in the home page.  in default mode, razor component would replace the content inside the div so that we would see Spinner loading and then disappear, but in WebAssemblyPrerendered mode, we don't have such "replace" action. Pls correct me if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=webassembly) (**the part before `Configuration for embedding Razor components into pages and views` section**) to try to reproduce your issue, you added code snippet below to surround the `<component>` tag

```
<div id="app">
        <img xxxx />
</div>
```

And this is my test result.

[image]

Since it's `WebAssemblyPrerendered`, so I don't have the default loading page.

[image]

In your symptom, you mentioned `image and spinner stay on the page when the app finishes loading` and I think this should be the expected behavior, because you have `<div id="app">` content inside the `_Host.cshtml` so they should be rendered into the home page. If we didn't use the `WebAssemblyPrerendered` mode, the Spinner and the img tag are placed in the client project index.html, after the page is loaded, they would be replaced by the razor component, I mean  in the default model, after we run the blazor wasm hosted project, it would load index.html first which contains `<div id="app">{Spinner and img here}</div>` first, after the razor component is loaded, razor component content should replace the content of the `<div id="app">`.

Anyway, follow the official document to do it.